# PDF pages with quartz

Tags: objective-c, iphone, quartz-graphics

Here's my code for getting the pages from a pdf document and create a pdf document with each page:

```
- (void)getPages {
NSString *pathToPdfDoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"security" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPdfDoc];

CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);

size_t numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);

for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 0);

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"./security%d.pdf", i];

    CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, [filename UTF8String], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
    CFRelease (path);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("My PDF File"));
    CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("My Name"));

    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, &pageRect, myDictionary);
    CFRelease(myDictionary);
    CFRelease(url);

    CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &pageRect);
    MyDrawPDFPageInRect(pdfContext, page, kCGPDFMediaBox, pageRect, 0, true);
    CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
    CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
}

CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
}

void MyDrawPDFPageInRect(CGContextRef context, CGPDFPageRef page, CGPDFBox box, CGRect rect, int rotation, bool preserveAspectRatio) {
CGAffineTransform m;

m = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, box, rect, rotation, preserveAspectRatio);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, m);
CGContextClipToRect(context, CGPDFPageGetBoxRect (page, box));
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The problem is that the pages appears in the filesystem, but they are empty.
Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PDF pages are numbered from 1. So this line:

```
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 0);
```

gives you a null page, which in turn gives you an empty page rect, and from then on you're drawing nothing into nothing. Moreover, it's the same nothing each time, because you're *always* getting page 0 rather than moving through the pages.

What you want instead is to make the loop variable go from 1, and use it to get the pages:

```
for ( size_t i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++ ) {
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);
```

Everything else should work as is, I think.

Comment: I would cry... I didn't see that I wrote there a 0 instead of the for variable... Thank you very much man! And also for the advise that pdf pages start from 1.